# Loop help While loop isn't working correctly

Tags: c++, while-loop

My code will not output more than one line, even if I keep inputting numbers. Why is my `while` loop doing this and how can I fix it?

- when I type in `r 12.3 45.6` and then `p 12.3 45.6` it only outputs the first input.
- if I enter anything besides `R r P p` it's supposed to output `Format error` and continue with the loop unless the user enters `q` which stops the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    float x;
    float y;
    float M;
    float th;
    char input;

    cin >> input; 

    while ((input != 'q') && (input != 'Q')) {// starts while loop wile not inputting eirther q or Q
        if ((input == 'r') || (input == 'R')) {

           cin >> x >> y; //user inputs x and y
         M = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); // M 
         th =  atan2(y,x) * (180 / M_PI);// theta in degrees

            cout << "POL -> REC: REC: X = " << fixed << setprecision(2)  << x << " Y = " << y << " POL: M = " << M << " A = " << th<< endl;
        }

        if((input == 'p') || (input == 'P')) { //If user inputs p or P excute rest of code below

         cin >> M;//user enters M
         cin >> th;// User enters theta
         
         x = (M * cos(M_PI / 180 * th)); // X into degrees
         y = M * sin(th * M_PI/180);// y into degrees

            cout << "REC -> POL: REC: X = " << fixed << setprecision(2)  << x << " Y = " << y << " POL: M = " << M << " A = " << th << endl;

        }

        if ((input != 'r') && (input != 'R') && (input != 'p') && (input != 'P')) {//if user enters anything besides p P q Q then output format error
            cout << "Format Error!" << endl;

        }
               break; //stops loop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move

```
cin >> input;
```

into the while-loop and the break statement should only be executed if q or Q is entered. Also you need to reset input to something before the next loop around. I have put it to blank for the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
   float x;
   float y;
   float M;
   float th;
   char input;

   while (true) 
   {
      cin >> input;

      if ((input == 'r') || (input == 'R')) {

         cin >> x >> y; //user inputs x and y
         M = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); // M 
         th = atan2(y, x) * (180 / M_PI);// theta in degrees

         cout << "POL -> REC: REC: X = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << " Y = " << y << " POL: M = " << M << " A = " << th << endl;


      }

      if ((input == 'p') || (input == 'P')) { //If user inputs p or P excute rest of code below


         cin >> M;//user enters M
         cin >> th;// User enters theta

         x = (M * cos(M_PI / 180 * th)); // X into degrees
         y = M * sin(th * M_PI / 180);// y into degrees

         cout << "REC -> POL: REC: X = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << " Y = " << y << " POL: M = " << M << " A = " << th << endl;


      }

      if ((input != 'r') && (input != 'R') && (input != 'p') && (input != 'P')) {//if user enters anything besides p P q Q then output format error
         cout << "Format Error!" << endl;
         break;
      }

      if (input == 'q' || input == 'Q')
       break; //stops loop

      input = ' ';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how would I reset the input

Comment: See my example at the end of the while-loop where I set it to blank to prepare for the next round.

Comment: I see that but I don't understand what I should put in there instead of the blank space.

Comment: Just leave it as anything that is not one of the input q, Q, p, P, r, R. So blank is fine!

Comment: Once I enter a number that is not pP or rR it outputs Format Error even  after I input q after it

Comment: But that is the expected behavior from your code. So what is the problem?

Comment: when I enter q the loop is supposed to stop which it does but if I enter lets say        P 12.34 45.67
r 30.0 40.0
p 98.7 123.4
f 12 60
q                                                                                                                                              the out put I get is REC -> POL: REC: X = 8.62 Y = 8.83 POL: M = 12.34 A = 45.67
POL -> REC: REC: X = 30.00 Y = 40.00 POL: M = 50.00 A = 53.13
REC -> POL: REC: X = -54.33 Y = 82.40 POL: M = 98.70 A = 123.40
Format Error!
Format Error!
Format Error!
Format Error!
Format Error!
Format Error!

Comment: It will only stop if you put a break; after Format error line. I have edited that in.

Comment: Then exclude q from the condition in that if statement. I should not have to do everything for you. Figure it out.